# C# WebAPI CRUD Get ByID operation passing 2 params

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In a standard CRUD operation GET a Product by ID, I believe you use this notation

```
/api/products/id
```

Now, if you are an authenticated user and you already have a Token that you suppose to send with each request, where do you pass the Token?

I believe the C# WebAPI only handles one param at the time, so is it safe to assume that for any Authenticated call where a Token is also expected, you should **NOT** use the GET type but instead the POST type?

Clients are from all types (IOs, Androids, Windows App, Web Browsers)

Comment: You can put the token in header, ex: `X-Auth-Token` key. For business data, put it in body or query of the request. Other information: timeout, cache, authentiation,... put them in header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you normally get the authorization token somewhere and then pass that token in the header. I don't think it is a good practice to pass that in the URL itself

and then in the api controller, you use the authorization attribute(a customized one if needed) to validate the token. by doing that you isolate the validation concern into a separate logic and allows reusable in other apis as well.

It has nothing to do with whether it is GET request or POST request.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this would work with any type of client (IOS, Android, Windows App ...) ?

Comment: of course, i think web api is designed for working with any platform, it is based on standard http protocol.

Comment: @Developer Yes, it works with any type of client that support http. Cookies is only for browser, so do not use it.

Comment: @dohaivu ...is headers part of the message or part of the browser?

Comment: @Developer headers is part of HTTP request/response. Any HTTP library can read/create it. Browser can read/create it too. You can use [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) on iOS, [HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) on Window Phone, [http package](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html) on Android to read/create HTTP header.